# Comparing R0 with R1 using assembly (Keil)

Tags: assembly, compare, 8051, keil

I have two values stored in `R0` and `R1`. I am comparing the two as follows:

```
MOV R3, #(R0 XOR R1)
CJNE R3,#0,NOT_EQUAL
```

Apparently it is not possible to use the XOR OPERATOR this way. 
Is there another way to compare `R0` with `R1` and check is they are equal or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to perform the `XOR` at runtime, you will have to use instructions to accomplish that. Unfortunately, the `XRL` instruction only operates on the `A` register, so you might have to do some rearranging. Assuming `A` is not available, but `R3` is, you can do:

```
MOV R3, A ; save A to R3
MOV A, R0
XRL A, R1
XCH A, R3 ; restore A and put the result into R3
CJNE R3, #0, NOT_EQUAL
```

If `A` is available, you can use the `CJNE` accepting a memory operand knowing that registers are memory mapped:

```
MOV A, R0
CJNE A, 1, NOT_EQUAL ; 1 is the bank0 address of R1
```